# How to Distinguish a User-Aborted Call from an Error (jquery file upload)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jQuery file upload plugin

```
this.manualPostData.submit().
    done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
         FSUtils.smartSuccess({
            content: Localize.tt('msg.uploadfile'),
            timeout: 6000
        });

    }).
    fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
       FSUtils.smartError({
          content: JSON.parse(jqXHR.responseText).msgDesc,
           timeout: 6000
        });
    }
```

My scenario is when I call `.submit()` of my file object it will send a request to the server and the file will be  uploaded successfully, but if the user clicks on cancel button at the time of uploading then I cancel my server request and it is handled by `.fail()`.

How can I know if the request is aborted by the user? When the request fails then **jqXHR parameter** has data but when the request is canceled by the user then **jqXHR parameter** is undefined so how to handle and **how to check if it is aborted by  the user** ?

I cancel a server request using these two lines

```
 this.manualPostData.abort()
 this.manualPostData = null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The trick is to check the response headers in the **XMLHttpRequest**
>   object. If there are no response headers (null or empty string,
>   depending on the browser), the server did not respond yet. That means
>   the user aborted.

Here’s a function that takes an **XMLHttpRequest** and tells you if the user aborted it.

```
function userAborted(jqXHR) {
  return !jqXHR.getAllResponseHeaders();
}
```

Now in your **.fails** callback call this **userAborted** function

```
.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
   if (!userAborted(jqXHR)) {
     alert('Normal Fail');
   }else{
     alert('User Aborted');
   }
 }
```

You can’t use **textStatus** and **errorThrown** to tell if the user aborted. They return the same values whether the user aborted or the server returned with an error.

> (I only tested a **500** error.)